# After leaving the job, salary is still credited in my account. what i should do now?

Tags: salary

I left the job during 2nd week of September month, but my salary is been credited even after leaving my job. that is I got salary for September, October and November month as well. what i should do now?

Comment: Have your contacted the company (probably HR or the payroll department, through your old manager if you don't have their contact information) yet?

Comment: Were there terms when you left that you would still be paid regularly as part of a severance package? Some companies may do that in some cases though I'd second the previous comment of asking the company what is happening.

Comment: It sounds like a clerical error.  The one thing I would caution here is *don't* spend the money before this is settled.  If you spend it and then the company demands it back (which they can legally do) you will have put yourself in a financial bind.  I'd recommend transferring it temporarily to a saving account, just to help you keep it isolated.

Comment: When they find out they kept paying you they will most likely demand their money back, or even sue you for not reporting it. I would contact them and have a cheque ready.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not you to blame for a salary not being stopped once you resigned, which means someone is not doing their job for your previous employer. Ethically it is a responsibility of yours to notify the company about this issue, and again this should be a decision to be made from your side.